# Nested Generic polymorphic return type in a class

Tags: java, generics, architecture, generic-programming

I have a class that will contain the response to be send to UI. The blueprint is as :

```
class Response<T extends CustomObject> {  
     private String var1;  
     private String var2;  
     private List<T> custom; (eg. customOne, customTwo)
}
```

I can have different objects like custom objects that are extending CustomObject and based upon that Response class will have different customObject list.
After applying service logic, I get a raw response and based upon the custom object I try to parse differently.
CusomOne and CustomTwo will have different structure as :

```
class CustomOne extends CustomObject {  
    private String v1;  
}  
class CustomTwo extends CustomObject {  
    private String v2;
}
```

I have an abstract parsing function that will be called based upon the object that is picked. The function is defined as :

```
public abstract ResponsePayLoad<? extends CustomObject> parseResponse(String response);
```

ReponsePayLoad is another class that has other fields including CustomObject. The Blueprint for class ResponsePayLoad is as :

```
class ResponsePayLoad<T extends CustomObject> {  
    private String varX;  
    private List<T> value;  
}
```

Parsing function for both customObjects will be like :

```
public ResponsePayLoad<customOne> parseResponse(String response){  
    CustomOne one = ; // parsingLogic  
    return one;  
}  
public ResponsePayLoad<customTwo> parseResponse(String response){  
   CustomTwo two = ; // parsingLogic  
    return two;  
}
```

In my service logic when I write the code as :

```
ResponsePayLoad<CustomObject> responseObj = parseResponse(response);
```

I need to typecast it to ResponsePayLoad that I don't want to.
Could anyone tell me how can I skip using "?" in abstract function and still maintain the same logic? Moreover I don't want to typecast the same as I defined above. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you return type of `parseResponse` is for instance `ResponsePayLoad<CustomOne>` and `ResponsePayLoad<CustomTwo>` respectively.

Then it's not possible to store the result in

`ResponsePayLoad<CustomObject> responseObj = parseResponse(response);`

Since you can not downcast the result. In a generic fashion you would use

`ResponsePayLoad<? extends CustomObject> responseObj = parseResponse(response);`

But again you store the `CustomOne` and `CustomTwo` objects as `CustomObject` which means you are losing the type information. Then a cast is necessarily.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you need to cast

```
ResponsePayLoad<CustomObject> responseObj = parseResponse(response);
```

since the `parseResponse` method returns ResponsePayload of unknown type (`ResponsePayLoad<? extends CustomObject>`).

All that is understood here is, that the unknown type can be a subtype of `CustomObject`. It could be `CustomObject` itself(as in your case), or some of its subclasses(`CustomOne`, `CustomTwo` etc.) but it need not literally extend `CustomObject`.

Hence casting the complete response into `ResponsePayload` further makes it generic enough, though you must be warned by the compilers over the unchecked cast while doing so.

[The doc around generics wildcards](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) explains this with a better example.

---

> ...how can I skip using "?" in abstract function and still maintain
>   the same logic?

The other way to avoid explicit type casting is to return `ResponsePayload` from your `parseResponse` method by declaring it as:

```
public abstract ResponsePayLoad parseResponse(String response);
```